# Delete user when deleting UserProfile

Tags: python, django

I created `UserProfile` (extends from User) and written to `settings.py`

```
 AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'mainapp.UserProfile'.
```

When I delete `UserProfile` (from admin area) I would delete also `User` item.

I try delete user so `self.user.delete()`, but method delete (in UserProfile) don't call. Why ?

This is my code:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = settings.PATH_AVATARS, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user.delete()
        super(UserProfile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, to answer *why "delete()" is not called from the admin*. This statement is:

1. **True in the case of deleting objects from the list view**, ie. /admin/auth/user/ check some boxes then click Actions -> delete), this is because the delete() method of a **queryset** is called,
2. **Wrong in the case of deleting an object from the change_form**, ie. /admin/auth/user/1/ click on delete, this is where the delete() method of the **object** is called

That said, [_delete signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete) are well supported. Here is how you can use it:

```
from django.db.models import signals

def delete_user(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        instance.user.delete()
signals.post_delete.connect(delete_user, sender=UserProfile)
```

This is how i tested it:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User; from testapp.models import UserProfile; User.objects.all().delete(); UserProfile.objects.all().delete()

In [2]: user=User(username='foo'); user.save()

In [3]: profile=UserProfile(user=user); profile.save()

In [4]: UserProfile.objects.all().delete()

In [5]: User.objects.all()
Out[5]: []
```

Of course, this also works when the delete() method **of the object** is called:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User; from testapp.models import UserProfile; User.objects.all().delete(); UserProfile.objects.all().delete()

In [2]: user=User(username='foo'); user.save()

In [3]: profile=UserProfile(user=user); profile.save()

In [4]: profile.delete()

In [5]: User.objects.all()
Out[5]: []
```

Note that because of [cascade delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects), this works both ways:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User; from testapp.models import UserProfile; User.objects.all().delete(); UserProfile.objects.all().delete()

In [2]: user=User(username='foo'); user.save()

In [3]: profile=UserProfile(user=user); profile.save()

In [4]: user.delete()

In [5]: User.objects.all()
Out[5]: []

In [6]: UserProfile.objects.all()
Out[6]: []
```

If you need to know more about signals, refer to [Django's extensive documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

Comment: Thanks, that works.

But now i have another trouble.

When i written signals.post_delete.connect(delete_user, sender=UserProfile) i must also write 

    from mainapp.models import UserProfile

and when i register - says error

IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mainapp_userprofile_user_id_key"

Comment: Can you open another topic and include more details (code) please ? I don't understand your comment very well ... Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, everything is ok, i move signals from file view.py to file signals.py and works well.

Comment: Sometimes, this code may be called twice and raise an exception the second time. To avoid that, add a dispatch_uid param like so: `signals.post_delete.connect(delete_user, sender=UserProfile, dispatch_uid='website.models.user_deleted')`. The dispatch_uid must be unique project wide so I recommend using the path to the file calling the signal.